# What version of Nagios NCPA installed?

Tags: nagios

How can I find out what version of Nagios NCPA tools is installed on my Linux box?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following curl command to return the agent version.

```
curl -k  'https://<ip address remote system>:5693/api/system/agent_version/?token=mytoken&check=1'
```

Alternatively, if you login to the backend GUI, the version is displayed on the main page.

```
https://<ipaddress>:5693/login
```